# How to implement a cart system in django

Tags: django

I'm  stuck on the logic of implementing a cart system for my Application. I have tried using Sessions but I can't seem to make it work. Please any answer would be well appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to get inspired in some open source projects that nail this specific task, or just use it, like [django-carton](https://github.com/lazybird/django-carton) which is a simple and lightweight application for shopping carts and wish lists.